# Test app without a UDID

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, ipad

I am a registered developer. I want to test my app on a lot of devices, is it possible I don't specify a UDID? So I can generate a generic app and test it on some alot of devices?

Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't have thought so, no - you'd either need all the UDIDs to register against you app. You might also be able to do this with an enterprise developer registration, but they only give those out to companies with more than 500 employees. Otherwise you'd need to get your app approved before it can be distributed to other devices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that's why the UDIDs are required; to prevent you from doing just that. :)  Regardless of your motives, you're limited to 100 test devices per year to prevent broad non-app-store distribution, and the UDID/certificate is what controls that.